# Can WordPress store comment cookies on two different computers?

Tags: comments, cookies, privacy

It's usual that WordPress stores comment author name and email in the user's browser cookies, so next time the visitor has to comment, they have their name and email already filled in automatically.

My question is:

**Is it possible for WordPress to store a visitor's comment cookies on two computers at different locations, but probably using the same ISP?**

I'm asking this because I've seen someone else's name and email address stored in the comment form of a WordPress powered blog I was reading. My computer is password protected and nobody used it except me. And this happened not once, not twice but many times (every time a random unknown name and email). Even I've seen a "Your comment is waiting moderation" message.

And since I believed every browser maintains it's cookies for its own, this behavior is strange to me.

__

EDIT:

```
Property    Value
Name        comment_author_b4f88879dbf70af24980db38c9197684
Value       Emma
Host        example.tld
Path        /
Expires     Fri, 20 Dec 2013 12:56:16 GMT
Secure      No
HttpOnly    No

Name        comment_author_email_b4f88879dbf70af24980db38c9197684
Value       email%40server.co.uk
Host        example.tld
Path        /
Expires     Fri, 20 Dec 2013 12:56:16 GMT
Secure      No
HttpOnly    No
```

Comment: +1, but I've never seen this before. Could you show us some example from your dev tools (I mean the cookie and it's values).

Comment: @kaiser do you mean cookie property and its value? See my edit in the above question.

Comment: Yeah, those cookies that seem to magically appear and it's values.

Comment: @kaiser: I edited my question.

Comment: Very kool - if all users would be like that :) One more question: Could you replace that with a real domain, so we could try it ourself? As I said, I've never seen that happening before.

Comment: Well, I don't wish to share the site URL in public, but I can tell you the site is running on WP v3.2.1 and is using a theme called NewsWire.

Comment: Is it a porn site? ;)

Comment: No. It's not a porn site, but something similar.

Comment: Could you please join us in chat (StopPress) and elaborate that? Maybe we can work something out.

Comment: I don't have enough reputations to join the chat.

Comment: We already upvoted you, but there're not enough users online to bring you above the 20rep border. Maybe you want to answer one or two other questions, so we can push you above the line? Just write a comment here if you're done, then we'll check your profile and push you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cookies are fine.

[image]

The secret is **caching**. The blog owner has set up a server side output caching that doesn’t stop when someone sends as cookie. It *should* – as you can see, because caching pages with personal data is … odd.

Lesson: Don’t cache personalized output.

Comment: Thanks toscho. The site is cached by the host provider as it seems.